# Horizontal scroll to the dynamic columns based on search in angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

In a table, I have multiple dynamic columns with the horizontal scrollbar. I need to implement the search functionality were user search for column name or column data. If the column name and data exist then my scrollbar should scroll to the specific column.

I have tried to implement this but couldn't able to figure out and I cannot use any third party library or tool for this small functionality.

For reference, I have seen the google chrome browser has such feature where if I  search through browser search it directly points to the specific column. I want something like this but not the browser search or any third party tool.

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller("ListController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.personalDetails = [
        {
            'fname':'Abc',
            'lname':'Abc',
            'email':'Abc@Abc.com',
            'demo': 'xyz.com',
            'Pnumber': '9892XXXXXX',
            'Address': 'XYZ'
        }
        ];
}]);
```

```css
.btn-primary{
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.container,.search{
  margin: 20px 0;
}

form{
    width: 200px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="ListController">     
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
               <div class='search'>
                 <input type="search" placeholder="search column" required/>
               </div>
                        <form>
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()" /></th>
                                        <th>Firstname</th>
                                        <th>Lastname</th>
                                        <th>Email</th>
                                        <th>demo</th>
                                        <th>Phone number</th>
                                        <th>Address</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr ng-repeat="personalDetail in personalDetails">
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="personalDetail.selected"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="personalDetail.fname" required/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="personalDetail.lname" required/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="personalDetail.email" required/></td>
                                             <td>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="personalDetail.demo" required/></td>
                                             <td>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="personalDetail.Pnumber" required/></td>
                                             <td>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="personalDetail.Address" required/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by using a couple jQuery functions, among with angular. Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sfajg8oL/1/)

1)Define a container element, where the scrolling shall take place

2)Find your target element, and then scroll to it.

in your controller

```
$scope.textChanged = function () 
 {
    var $container = $('#myform'),
    $scrollTo = $('th').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === $scope.filter;});

    if($scrollTo.length > 0)
    {
        $container.scrollLeft(
        $scrollTo.offset().left - $container.offset().left + $container.scrollLeft());
    }
    else
    {
       $container.scrollLeft(-$container.scrollLeft());
    }

 }
```

Note:If you want the match to be partial, use

```
$scrollTo =  $('th:contains(' + $scope.filter + ')');
```

Then, in your html:

```
<input type="search" ng-change='textChanged()' ng-model='filter' placeholder="search column" required/>
```

and add id to form to locate it correctly

```
<form id='myform'>
```

finally add `$scope.filter` variable to your controller

```
app.controller("ListController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.filter = '';
```

Comment: Thanks it helps to figure out the solution.